# If [string] in [string] not working for requested webpage text

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am trying to open a webpage and scrape some strings from it into a list. The list would ultimately be populated by all of the names displayed on the webpage. In trying to do so, my code looks like this:

```
    import xlsxwriter, urllib.request, string, http.cookiejar, requests


def main():

    username = 'john.mauran'
    password = 'fZSUME1q'
    log_url = 'https://aries.case.com.pl/'
    dest_url = 'https://aries.case.com.pl/main_odczyt.php?strona=eksperci'
    login_values = {'username' : username , 'password' : password }
    r = requests.post(dest_url, data=login_values, verify=False, allow_redirects=False)

    open_sesame = r.text
    #reads the expert page
    readpage_list = open_sesame.splitlines()
    #opens up a new file in excel
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('expert_book.xlsx')
    #adds worksheet to file
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    #initializing the variable used to move names and dates
    #in the excel spreadsheet
    boxcoA = ""
    boxcoB = ""
    #initializing expert attribute variables and lists
    url_ticker = 0
    name_ticker = 0
    raw_list = []
    url_list = []
    name_list= []
    date_list= []
    #this loop goes through and finds all the lines
    #that contain the expert URL and name and saves them to raw_list::
    #raw_list loop

    for i in open_sesame:
        if '<tr><td align=left><a href=' in i:
            raw_list += i
    if not raw_list:
        print("List is empty")
    if raw_list:
        print(raw_list)

main()
```

As you can see, all I want to do is take the lines from the text returned by the Requests operation which start with the following characters '

Comment: You should use a xml/html parser for scraping a website. http://lxml.de/ or http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but this doesn't make any sense:

```
for i in open_sesame:
    if '<tr><td align=left><a href=' in i:
        raw_list += i
```

First of all, if you iterate over `open_sesame`, which is a string, each item in the iteration will be a character in the string.  Then `'<tr><td align=left><a href=' in i` will always be false.

Second of all, `raw_list += i` is not how you append an item to a list.

Finally, why is the variable called `open_sesame`?  Is it a joke?

Comment: OK thank you. I did not understand that the request returns a single string. So is there a method you would use to reorganize the request into multiple lines of string rather than 1 big string?.

Comment: OK thank you. I did not understand that the request returns a single string. So is there a method you would use to reorganize the request into multiple lines of string rather than 1 big string?.

Comment: It looks like you already figured that part out.  The `.splitlines()` method splits a string into lines.

Comment: I tried that. Printing out the result of that operation showed just as many strings in the file as there were characters, meaning a gigantic column, which was no good. As vincent suggested, I learned to use beautifulsoup.